# Post to website using Curl

Tags: php, post, curl

Hi I'm new to Curl and starting to try things up. I've read some articles but I need to do something that I can't seem find in the internet.

Here's what I want, I want to post to http://www.yellow-pages.ph/search this is a yellow pages website.

Now, If I want to find Jolibee in Makati City I will post http://www.yellow-pages.ph/search/jolibee/makati .

What I want to is to use curl to post http://www.yellow-pages.ph/search/jolibee/makati and get
every data that is contained in their  element tag and store it in array. How do I do it in CURL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't post in terms of HTTP request, you issue a get request, which you can do with the following code:

```
// User agent
$browser = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"    
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.yellow-pages.ph/search/jolibee/makati/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $browser
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled, you can use `file_get_contents($url)` to replace all the cURL codes (if you don't have data to pass to the URL).

Comment: Great tip @Raptor, I didn't know that. What about other parameters, e.g. user agent? Sometimes request may be blocked if headers aren't set accordingly.

Comment: User agent is not required in most cases, and your user agent is suspicious, as it contains multiple browser signatures.

Comment: You can use same for POST, use CURL_POST to true. http://www.technologyworkshops.net/tutorials-f39/curl-using-get-method-with-php-t135.html